# Graphing M(water)*C(water)*ΔT = M(metal)*C(metal)*ΔT

Tags: thermodynamics

i'm currently doing an experiment, the goal of which is to determine the specific heat capacity of a certain metal. We are using the calorimeter method to do this. I want to graph the equation of Heat (Q=mcΔT) for both the water inside the calorimeter and the metal, meaning I would graph:

m(water)c(water)ΔT(water) = m(metal)c(metal)ΔT(metal)

where: m=mass, c=specific heat capacity, ΔT=change in temperature.

My question is if I graph the first half of the equation: m(water)c(water)ΔT(water) on the y-axis, is there a way I can get c(metal) as my gradient?

I know every value except for c(metal).
Multiple trials were done with different starting temperatures of the metal, therefore I would like to create a graph. From my knowledge it should be possible to graph:

m(water)c(water)ΔT(water) = m(metal)c(metal)ΔT(metal)

- where the first half of the equation is the Y-axis
- m(metal)*c(metal) is the gradient and
- ΔT(metal) is the x-axis.

Could anyone verify if this is possible or if my thinking is correct? It's been a while since I've had to do anything like this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should make a graph of the final temperature of the water and metal as y and the starting water temperature as x.  The slope of the line will be related to the c of the metal, and you can determine the c from the slope (knowing the other parameters).

ADDENDUM

$$T=\frac{m_{water}c_{water}}{(m_{metal}c_{metal}+m_{water}c_{water})}T_{0,water}+\frac{m_{metal}c_{metal}T_{0,metal}}{(m_{metal}c_{metal}+m_{water}c_{water})}$$

I assume you are using the same initial metal temperature in all cases and varying the initial water temperature.

Another form of the equation is:
$$(T-T_{0,water})=\frac{m_{metal}c_{metal}}{(m_{metal}c_{metal}+m_{water}c_{water})}(T_{0,metal}-T_{0,water})$$

So plot $(T-T_{0,water})$ vs $(T_{0,metal}-T_{0,water})$.  You should get a straight line through the origin with a slope of $\frac{m_{metal}c_{metal}}{(m_{metal}c_{metal}+m_{water}c_{water})}$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Im still a bit confused, if I use your method, will the final slope of my line be m(metal) * c(metal)? This is what I originally thought, but that would leave out some of the other parameters like c and m of water.

Comment: If you actually solve the heat balance equation you presented for the final temperature in terms of the physical properties and the initial temperatures, what do you get?

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what you mean. Are you referrring to the mcΔT=mcΔT equation?
When I graph the final temperature vs.  the starting water temperature as you  suggested, what exactly would my slope be (what variables are in it besides c(metal))

Comment: $$m_{metal}c_{metal}(T-T_{0,metal})=m_{water}c_{water}(T_{0,water}-T)$$Solve for T.

Comment: Which would give
T= (Mw×Cw×T(initial, water) + T(initial, metal)×Mm×Cm)  /  Mw×Cw + Mm×Cm
This should then be my slope for the graph (??)

Comment: Can you work this into the form y=ms+b, with y=T and $x=T_{0,water}$?

Comment: Not sure if correct but:

Comment: I tried but ended up getting (Mw×Cw)/(MwCw) for b, which equals one which should be wrong.. not sure where my mistake was

Comment: You have an algebra error.  To get this right, you gotta get the algebra right.

Comment: I've gone through it a few times and haven't been able to find it. No clue what went wrong

Comment: See my addendum

Comment: Im sorry, I don't think  I really made this clear - I changed the temperature of the metal piece each trial

Comment: And the initial water temperature stayed the same?

Comment: It changed only slightly as it was tap water. I have the initial water temperature for each trial recorded, it differs by maybe one degree celsius

Comment: Then see the next part of my addendum.